# is it possible to use team explorer for version control without buying license for visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, version-control, tfs

I downloaded the team explorer 2005 and when I tried to open the application from source control , I am getting the error .csproj applicaion type is not installed.

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: What is the exact text or the error?

Comment: Do you also have Visual Studio itself installed? Team Explorer is just the isolated client interface to TFS.

Comment: we have a professional visual studio on developers machine ..but we want to keep the track of deployed code in staging envioremtn where no development , only check in , check out of code using team explorer ..not usre if its possible without buying license for visual studio

Comment: you should be able to check out the files without any bother, it's only if you want to open the projects/solutions that you'll need Visual Studio installed - Rather than opening the project, you should just perform a checkout of the files from the Source Control Explorer window.

Comment: thaks for your comment! I think this should solve my problem. I was trying to open sln to checkin checkout which i don't need to do.

Answer (score 4):

In order to open a .csproj you will need to install a version of Visual Studio that supports .csproj`s.  There are free versions, called express SKU's, of Visual Studio that should help you out here.  It, and the other express SKU's, are available at the following link

- http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/

Comment: Jared, thanks for your response ..first the link point to 2008  and I want 2005 and I am not sure if express edition can be used in a company . my understanding is , express edition is only for individaul ..am I wrong ???

Comment: Microsoft no longer supply the 2005 Express SKUs, 2008's been out for two years, and 2010's out in a few months - both of which will open 2005 .csproj files, but will also want to convert them to the 2008 version - which is mostly just a version number change at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [CAL (Client Access License)](http://www.cdw.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=978082) to run just team explorer and access the TFS functionality to check in and check out and other things. If you're wanting to open the projects and make changes you'll need a license for visual studio. There are many different options there. I don't believe you can use the free one in your situation. Using VS professional you'll still need to get the CAL as well to access TFS but if you get one of the team editions of VS you will have the TFS CAL included.

That's how I understand the licensing for TFS/VS but I'm not an expert and it would probably be best to ask your supplier or microsoft about licensing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Team Explorer allows one to interface with TFS which includes accessing project documentation, filing bugs, and possibly retrieving source code.  However, I believe you need Visual Studio to open up project/solution files (i.e. a developer task).

This might be different with Visual Studio 2010 but that's the sales pitch we heard regarding 2008.

Answer (score 0):

In summary, although you need the specific module that loads C# projects. When you installed Team Explorer, although you have the basic IDE, that module is not loaded (is similar to when you install SQL Server client - you have the Visual Studio IDE, but the only module loaded is the SQL Server management Studio). As some of the other guys suggested, try to install Visual Studio C# Express (you can find more information here - http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/ - click on Microsoft® Visual C#® 2008 Express Edition). Notice that later on if you want to use web application, you will need to install the web edition and so forth.

When you install Visual Studio Professional (or Team Suite) most of those modules are installed by default.

I hope this info helps.